# How to add an item to a PHP array on HTML user input

Tags: php, html, arrays

```
  <?php
$friends = array('notch',);
foreach ($friends as $friend) {
echo '<img src="http://mcapi.ca/avatar/'.$friend.'"/>';
}
?>
```

I would like to change the item in the PHP array on HTML user input from a textarea. **Could someone provide the HTML & PHP code in order for this to work?** The array changing would mean that an image would update. Is this possible to do without having to reload the page for the image to show? I am new to PHP, so my knowledge is fuzzy. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How to add an item to a PHP array on HTML user input -> Like This -> `$friend['some_key']`

Comment: I think `javascript`/`jquery` is better here than `php`. Unless you retrieve the data from a database, `php` is not needed

Comment: @Tesseract I would, but the API I'm using (MCAPI) is a PHP api. Unless you know another way to do this (replacing a part of an image link) with JS

Comment: PHP can't produce dynamic, non-page-reloading websites, that's what javascript / jquery is for. PHP is executed server-side, while website is rendered on client computer. You need a client-side script that will make a website update itself.

Comment: @schroedingersKat Ok so would I just make a JS script replacing     http://mcapi.ca/avatar/THIS_TEXT the "THIS_TEXT" text with what the user has input?

Comment: Specifically, you'll need to look into websites designed with AJAX in mind. However you need to ask yourself if this dynamicity is really needed - some people will disable scripts in their browsers by default. They might not be able to use your website properly. Unless you check if client-side scripts are enabled and on that basis redirect client to javascript / non-javascript version of your website.

Comment: @schroedingersKat Ok got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As all the comments already say:

No, this is not possible with PHP. PHP runs on the server, prepares a page (html output), and this page is sent to your browser. Therefore, user input can only happen after PHP has finished its work. What you want to do can only be done on the client side - have a look at JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As said, you are talking about 2 different worlds(Client side/Front end and server side/Backend).

One thing you could do is, use something like KnockoutJS(or some MVVM/framework, there are several) and when the changes happens, you can interact with your php in execution time without having to reload the page as you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

i have modify your code, hope so it will help you to sort out your problem.

```
<?php
$friends = array('notch'); // i have remove comma after 'notch'
<script>
var item = document.getElementById("put here your input text field id").value;</script>

foreach ($friends as $friend) {
echo '<img src="http://mcapi.ca/avatar/'.$friend.'"/>';
}
?>
```